# Python/Selenium - find_elements_by_class_name with long class name

Tags: python, css, selenium

Quite basic issue in selenium.

There is a class in a site I am trying to iterate over (no IDs, no name), but extremely long class name such as `class="my really long crappy class name with space"`

I am trying `mydriver.find_elements_by_class_name(idClass);` where `mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()`.

I also tried `my.really.long.crappy.class.name.with.space` and this as well does not work (saw this as a posted solution on some other questions like me. When I run this I do not get an error  but my result is of size zero.

The following function is what I am currently using, and I am hitting my print

```
        def getElementByClass(idClass):
            a=[];
            try:
                print idClass;
                a = mydriver.find_elements_by_class_name(idClass);
                return a;
            except:
                print 'crap';
```

Comment: What `idClass` value are you passing in?

Comment: @alecxe I tried `"my really long crappy class name with space"` and `"my.really.long.crappy.class.name.with.space"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find_elements_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector):

```
mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.class1.class2.class3');
```

where `class1`, `class2` and `class3` are the class names that the element has.

Or, another option is to use [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath):

```
mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="my really long crappy class name with space"]')
```

You can also replace `*` with the tag name if you know it beforehand.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sure. Can you unpack what the //* is doing?

Comment: @jasonm it means any element, any tag name. You have not mentioned what element are you looking for. If you know what the element is, just replace `*` with it. For example, `//div[...]`.